# How to use spring-boot-maven-plugin to create a startup jar file in a multi-module project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jar, multi-module

I need to build a jar file of my project using spring-boot-maven-plugin. When I was building a project without modules , everything worked out. I decided to try the same thing, but already in a multi-module project. As a result, I got this error:
Unable to find main class

Here is my parent Pom.xml:

```
<project>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project Name</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>Controller</module>
        <module>Model</module>
        <module>View</module>
        <module>Execute</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>repackage</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <classifier>spring-boot</classifier>
                                <mainClass>
                                    ru.kwork.Main
                                </mainClass>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here are the children Pom.xml:

```
<project>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>Project Name</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <artifactId>Model</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

---

```
<project>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>Project Name</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <artifactId>Controller</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>Model</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

---

```
<project>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>Project Name</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <artifactId>View</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>Controller</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

---

```
<project>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>Project Name</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <artifactId>Execute</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>View</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

---

The main class is located in the Execute module.

I have seen in similar questions that they add to the child ones Pom.xml here is this plugin:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
```

But it didn't help me/or I did something wrong.
I also saw a couple of solutions on the Internet, but I didn't understand them. I hope you can help me solve this problem and figure out the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried without the `<executions> (...) </executions>` configuration on `spring-boot-maven-plugin`?

Comment: @JoãoDias, No. And then where to specify the main class?

Comment: In Spring Boot you mark the main class with `@SpringBootApplication`. This class must have the usual `public static void main(String[] args)` method. Check here an example --> https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-annotations#spring-boot-application.

Comment: @JoãoDias, I have this annotation above the main class.

Comment: @JoãoDias, But it still doesn't help.

Comment: Do you have multiple annotations like that across the modules?

Comment: @JoãoDias, can you give me example?

Comment: I was just asking if you have multiple `@SpringBootApplication` annotations in your modules. Do you?

Comment: @JoãoDias, I'm sorry, I didn't understand it right away. No. I have this annotation only in one module above the main method.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `spring-boot-maven-plugin` from your parent `pom-xml` and the following to your module that contains `@SpringBootApplication`:

```xml
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

It will search for the main method to flag as a runnable class, so you don't need to explicitly configure it.